# ¿Cómo poner una imagen dentro de una tabla?

Tags: php, html, html5, xampp

Me gustaría que me dijeran cómo podría aparecer una imagen dentro de una tabla ya que tengo mi código así y no me muestra ninguna imagen. Aclaro en la base de datos hay un campo en el cual se encuentra la dirección de la imagen, en la base de datos toma el campo numero 11 de la tabla contando desde 0 espero me ayuden a que salga la imagen.

Cabe mencionar que me sale esto en la pagina:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Vestidos/imagenes/imagen4.jpg

¿Cómo lo soluciono? Éste es mi código:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">

    <div class="table-responsive col-md-12"><br><br>

        <table class="table table-striped navbar-inverse">
            <tr id="cabecera" align="center">
                <th id="cabecera">ID</th>
                <th id="cabecera">Categoria</th>
                <th id="cabecera">Nombre</th>
                <th id="cabecera">Cantidad</th>
                <th id="cabecera">Género</th>
                <th id="cabecera">Descripcion</th>
                <th id="cabecera">Disponible</th>                           
                <th id="cabecera">Costo</th>
                <th id="cabecera">Precio</th>   
                <th id="cabecera">Descuento</th>
                <th id="cabecera">Fecha Alta</th>   
                <th id="cabecera">Imagen</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_row()) {
                    echo "<form method='POST'><tr>";
                    for ($i=0; $i < count($fila); $i++) { 
                        if($i==0){
                            echo "<td>".$fila[$i]."</td>
                            <input type='hidden' name='clave' value='$fila[$i]'>";
                        } 
                        elseif ($i!=11) 
                        {                                   
                            echo "<td>".$fila[$i]."</td>";
                        }
                        elseif($i==11)
                        {
                            echo"<td >  <img src='".$fila[$i]."' width=100 height=100  >    </img></td>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</tr></form>";
                }
                $resultado->close();
            ?>              
        </table>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Recordá que la imagen está grabada en el servidor y la página se ve en el navegador (cliente), vos le estás pasando la ruta hacia el archivo en disco (del servidor) cuando en realidad le deberías estar pasando la URL (absoluta o relativa) hacia el archivo, te debería quedar algo como "/imagenes/imagen4.jpg".

Otro consejo al margen de tu pregunta, sacale el `id="cabecera"` a todos los th o reemplazalo por el atributo class.

Answer (score 1):

Al ver que te muestra la ruta file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Vestidos/imagenes/imagen4.jpg me hace pensar que estas usando rutas absolutas al guardar la ubiccación de la imagen, podrías probar usando rutas relativas para que guardes algo como ../imagenes/imagen4.jpg